# Bitcoind fails to start on Centos 7

Tags: bitcoind, error, centos

When I execute bitcoind on CentOS 7 I get this error:

```
Unable to start HTTP server. See debug log for details.
 bitcoind: scheduler.cpp:19: CScheduler::~CScheduler(): Assertion `nThreadsServicingQueue == 0' failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of known issues on the compile side of things (under CentOS) which could be related: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/6432.